# How to make a CSS grid with fixed number of columns, unknown number of rows/items and variable item height without vertical space between items?

Tags: css, css-grid

I would like to achieve this layout using CSS grids:

[image: a grid layout]

I want a fixed number of columns (3). I don't know how many items will be in the grid and thus I don't know the number of rows either.

I wrote the following:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

But then, if the height of 2 is much bigger than the height of 1 and 3, on the second rows, all items will be displayed at the same level (under the end of 2). Whereas I would like 4 to start just under 1, 5 under 2 and 3 under 6 as shown in the picture.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/native-css-masonry-layout-css-grid/